# Firebase Authenticate using a Phone Number: use of unresolved identifier AuthAPNSTokenTypeProd and UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData error

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication, appdelegate

I am integrating Authenticate with Firebase on iOS using a Phone Number and I am having errors in the initial implementation of the procedure as mentioned in their document in this [link.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth)

I followed the procedure mentioned their, installed the pods and imported the firebase SDK.
The error comes in the following two methods:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
  // Pass device token to auth
  Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenTypeProd)

  // Further handling of the device token if needed by the app
  // ...
}
```

and

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData)
    return
  }
  // This notification is not auth related, developer should handle it.
}
```

It says "**use of unresolved identifier 'AuthAPNSTokenTypeProd'**" and "**use of unresolved identifier 'UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData'**".

I am not sure about the procedure I am missing in the implementation. I have gone through the implementation procedure many times, I can't find the mistake.

Comment: Did you tried this on an Simulator or a real device?

Comment: I was working on device but that doesn't matter because the project won't run itself as its a compile time error. Anyways if I exclude these methods from code, let method swizzling be active, and go forward with implementation, Firebase Auth is working. But If want to disable method swizzling, then I am required to write those methods and that doesn't work out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try following code

```
Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.prod)
```

and this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
        return
    }
    // This notification is not auth related, developer should handle it.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out `AuthAPNSTokenTypeProd`is not a data type or enum case. It seems like there's a mistake in the Phone Authentication implementation steps for iOS.

You're looking for `AuthAPNSTokenType` which is associated with the Obj-C enum: `FIRAuthAPNSTokenType`.

You can find the source inside the **FirebaseAuth** framework/dependency.

So the solution to one of your problems should be to change this line:

`Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenTypeProd)`

to this:

`Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.prod)`

Docs: [Authenticate with Firebase on iOS using a Phone Number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth)

API Reference: [FirebaseAuth Framework Reference - FIRAuthAPNSTokenType](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums#firauthapnstokentype)